# Go Docker Container Fail: "Exit Code 1"

Tags: docker, go

i'am trying to running my Go Apps in Docker container, but it fail and give error exit code 1. The application works well in my local machine but not in Docker.

Below is my Dockerfile.

```
FROM golang:1.8 as goimage

RUN go get -u github.com/golang/dep/cmd/dep

COPY . src/github.com/aditmayapada/tryout
WORKDIR src/github.com/aditmayapada/tryout


ENV PORT 9090

RUN dep ensure

RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build -o bin/main

FROM alpine:3.6 as baseimagealp
RUN apk add --no-cache bash
ENV WORK_DIR=/docker/bin
WORKDIR $WORK_DIR
# RUN mkdir src/github.com/aditmayapada/tryout/bin
# WORKDIR src/github.com/aditmayapada/tryout/bin
COPY --from=goimage /go/src/github.com/aditmayapada/tryout/bin ./
ENTRYPOINT /docker/bin/main
EXPOSE 9090
```

And below is my apps repository that i want to deploy in Docker
https://github.com/aditmayapada/tryout

I have tried to get logs using docker events, and i only get this
[Logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2LpyG.png)

Then i tried to use --logs in docker but its not showing anything.

Am i missing something here? because my apps run well in my local machine... Thank you.

Comment: error 1 is "operation not permitted"  so I guess you are tripping over some kind of resource or security constraint

Comment: I generally like to cross compile using GOOS and GOARCH and not do the actual build on the docker container.  You may be able to get smaller images that way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have briefly looked at your code and found that app could be finished in a case when `connection.Ping()` return err
https://github.com/aditmayapada/tryout/blob/master/main.go#L44
I recommend adding some logging in this space to identify a point of exit. It seems something is wrong with connection to DB in docker.

Comment: yeah you right! its because connection to DB. Thank you very much